# Adding Custom Delete (Back,toFront) Button to Controls

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas, fabricjs

I would like to know if there is an easy way to add a delete, bring to front, bring to back 
function into the existing **fabric.js** object controls.

At the moment I can only click on buttons which would delete object, bring to front etc.

I am working on finding a solution to be able to **press X (on the upper right corner) on the object and delete the object.**

I guess it will have to do with overwriting, wrapping or subclassing the existing control object.

Maybe I have overseen something and there is an easy solution? Please no Div Wrapper.

[image: Fabric.js Canvas Object Selection Delete X]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Fabric.js does not offer any simple mean of adding controls to objects.
If you want to create your own controls, you will have to overwrite the Object class, notably:

- override `drawControls`, to draw your custom button
- you will need to store the button's coordinates, so that you can detect when the user clicks them. C.f. `_setCornerCoords` and `_findTargetCorner`
- incorporate your action somewhere in `__onMouseDown`

You don't need to take care of 'undrawing' the controls, as the whole canvas is re-rendered when an object is de-selected.

I hope this helps, and good luck :)

Comment: So I guess this is the closest we can get? :) I have seen `drawControls` inside `object_interactivity.mixin.js`. I will take a look into that. If there is no other answer you get the bounty.

Comment: @zer02, did you get any solution for it? I also want to implement similar thing.

Answer (score 5):

I have implemented it via positioning an html element

```
canvas.on('object:selected',function(e){


        jQuery(".deleteBtn").remove(); 
        var btnLeft = e.target.oCoords.mt.x;
        var btnTop = e.target.oCoords.mt.y - 25;
        var widthadjust=e.target.width/2;
        btnLeft=widthadjust+btnLeft-10;
        var deleteBtn = '<p" class="deleteBtn" title="Delete" style="position:absolute;top:'+btnTop+'px;left:'+btnLeft+'px;cursor:pointer;" title="Remove object">&#10005;</p>';
        jQuery(".canvas-container").append(deleteBtn);
        //.canvas-container is the parent div to the canvas positioned relative via CSS



    });

canvas.on('mouse:down',function(e){
    if(canvas.getActiveObject())
    {

    }
    else
    {
         jQuery(".deleteBtn").remove(); 
    }
});


canvas.on('object:modified',function(e){


        jQuery(".deleteBtn").remove(); 
        var btnLeft = e.target.oCoords.mt.x;
        var btnTop = e.target.oCoords.mt.y - 25;
        var widthadjust=e.target.width/2;
        btnLeft=widthadjust+btnLeft-10;
        var deleteBtn = '<p" class="deleteBtn" title="Delete" style="position:absolute;top:'+btnTop+'px;left:'+btnLeft+'px;cursor:pointer;" title="Remove object">&#10005;</p>';
        jQuery(".canvas-container").append(deleteBtn);
        //.canvas-container is the parent div to the canvas positioned relative via CSS



    });


//THE DELETE BUTTON CLICK EVENT
 jQuery(document).on('click',".deleteBtn",function(){


    if(canvas.getActiveObject())
    {
         canvas.remove(canvas.getActiveObject());
//this would remove the currently active object on stage,
         jQuery(this).remove();
         jQuery(".deleteBtn").remove();
    }


     })
```

Comment: Please check the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/86bTc/8/) with the above implemented code

Comment: The same solution I am applying in my canvas. All thing is working fine, but when user rotates the image then `delete` image could not be placed on right place. May I know what should I try to add delete image when user rotates ?

Answer (score 3):

i believe the the solution with the dom elements is not so stable but its ok if it covers your needs,
 I also needed to change the default object's corner buttons , to my custom buttons for my web application. 
I use ,

1. 'alter size' button, /*i dont use it any more for my reasons*/
2. 'delete object' button
3. 'edit object' button
4. 'rotate object' button

so you have to change 2 things in order to succeed that:

**1.** change the private function '_drawControl' from fabric.js file. This is about on line 13367 (on my fabric.js). On that function fabric draws the default cornet buttons of objects and show them on seleced.
We can easily change the png to our custom ones.

**below is my changed _drawControl(fabric.js):**

```
     _drawControl: function(control, ctx, methodName, left, top, flipiX, flipiY) {

              var sizeX = this.cornerSize / this.scaleX,
                  sizeY = this.cornerSize / this.scaleY;

              if (this.isControlVisible(control)) {
                isVML || this.transparentCorners || ctx.clearRect(left, top, sizeX, sizeY);

          var SelectedIconImage = new Image();
          var lx='';
          var ly='';
          var n='';

          switch (control)
            {
            case 'tl':      
              if (flipiY) { ly='b'; } else { ly = 't'; }
              if (flipiX) { lx='r'; } else { lx = 'l'; }
              break;
            case 'tr':
              if (flipiY) { ly='b'; } else { ly = 't'; }
              if (flipiX) { lx='l'; } else { lx = 'r'; }
              break;
            case 'bl':
              if (flipiY) { ly='t'; } else { ly = 'b'; }
              if (flipiX) { lx='r'; } else { lx = 'l'; }
              break;
            case 'br':
              if (flipiY) { ly='t'; } else { ly = 'b'; }
              if (flipiX) { lx='l'; } else { lx = 'r'; }
              break;
            default:
              ly=control.substr(0, 1);
              lx=control.substr(1, 1);
              break;
            }

          control=ly+lx;

          switch (control)
            {
            case 'tl':      

//my custom png for the object's top left corner
              SelectedIconImage.src = 'assets/img/icons/draw_control/icon_rotate.png';
              break;
            case 'tr':
              if (flipiX && !flipiY) { n='2'; }
              if (!flipiX && flipiY) { n='3'; }
              if (flipiX && flipiY) { n='4'; }

//my custom png for the object's top right corner
                SelectedIconImage.src = 'assets/img/icons/draw_control/icon_delete.png';
              break;
            case 'mt':
              SelectedIconImage.src = //add your png here if you want middle top custom image;
              break;
            case 'bl':
              if (flipiY) { n='2'; }
              SelectedIconImage.src = //add your png here if you want bottom left corner custom image;
              break;
            case 'br':
              if (flipiX || flipiY) { n='2'; }
              if (flipiX && flipiY) { n=''; }
//my custom png for the object's bottom right corner
              SelectedIconImage.src = 'assets/img/icons/draw_control/icon_settings.png';
              break;
            case 'mb':
              SelectedIconImage.src = //middle bottom png here ;
              break;
            case 'ml':
              SelectedIconImage.src = 'assets/img/icons/draw_control/icono_escala_horizontal'+n+'.jpg';
              break;
            case 'mr':
              SelectedIconImage.src = //middle right png here;
              break;
            default:
              ctx[methodName](left, top, sizeX, sizeY);
              break;
            }

     // keep middle buttons size fixed
            if (control == 'tl' || control == 'tr' || control == 'bl' || control == 'br'
            || control == 'mt' || control == 'mb' || control == 'ml' || control == 'mr')
            {
              sizeX = 19;
              sizeY = 19;
              ctx.drawImage(SelectedIconImage, left, top, sizeX, sizeY);
            }


              try {
                ctx.drawImage(SelectedIconImage, left, top, sizeX, sizeY); 

              } catch (e) {
                if (e.name != "NS_ERROR_NOT_AVAILABLE") {
                  throw e;
                }
              }


        }
  },
```

2. As **Toon Nelissen** mentioned before, i overide the `fabric.Canvas.prototype.__onMouseDown` function , and control my custom buttons.

   ```
   fabric.Canvas.prototype.__onMouseDown = function (e) {

   // accept only left clicks
   var isLeftClick  = 'which' in e ? e.which === 1 : e.button === 1;
   if (!isLeftClick && !fabric.isTouchSupported) {
       return;
   }

   if (this.isDrawingMode) {
       this._onMouseDownInDrawingMode(e);
       return;
   }

   // ignore if some object is being transformed at this moment
   if (this._currentTransform) {
       return;
   }

   var target = this.findTarget(e), 
   pointer = this.getPointer(e, true);

   //if user clicked on the top right corner image
   if (target && target.__corner === 'tr') {
             //my code goes here
       }
   } else {
       // save pointer for check in __onMouseUp event
       this._previousPointer = pointer;

       var shouldRender = this._shouldRender(target, pointer),
         shouldGroup = this._shouldGroup(e, target);

       if (this._shouldClearSelection(e, target)) {
           this._clearSelection(e, target, pointer);
       } else if (shouldGroup) {
           this._handleGrouping(e, target);
           target = this.getActiveGroup();
       }

       if (target && target.selectable && !shouldGroup) {
       this._beforeTransform(e, target);
       this._setupCurrentTransform(e, target);
       }
       // we must renderAll so that active image is placed on the top canvas
       shouldRender && this.renderAll();

       this.fire('mouse:down', { target: target, e: e });
       target && target.fire('mousedown', { e: e });
   }
   ```

   };

For the rest corners we as well write the appropriate snippet(inside __onMouseDown):

```
 //if user clicked on the bottom right corner image
        if (target && target.__corner === 'br') {
             //my code here
         }else{
            //the same as 'tr'
        }

 //if user clicked on the top left corner image
            if (target && target.__corner === 'tl') {
                 //my code here
             }else{
                //the same as 'tr'
            }

 //if user clicked on the bottom left corner image
            if (target && target.__corner === 'bl') {
                 //my code here
             }else{
                //the same as 'tr'
            }
```

below is a screenshot of my web app's custom images

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can try with html buttons. Look at the example:

http://fabricjs.com/interaction-with-objects-outside-canvas/

Here is the code example:

```
    (function() {
  var canvas = this.__canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');
  fabric.Object.prototype.transparentCorners = false;
  fabric.Object.prototype.originX = fabric.Object.prototype.originY = 'center';

  fabric.Canvas.prototype.getAbsoluteCoords = function(object) {
    return {
      left: object.left + this._offset.left,
      top: object.top + this._offset.top
    };
  }

  var btn = document.getElementById('inline-btn'),
      btnWidth = 85,
      btnHeight = 18;

  function positionBtn(obj) {
    var absCoords = canvas.getAbsoluteCoords(obj);

    btn.style.left = (absCoords.left - btnWidth / 2) + 'px';
    btn.style.top = (absCoords.top - btnHeight / 2) + 'px';
  }

  fabric.Image.fromURL('../lib/pug.jpg', function(img) {

    canvas.add(img.set({ left: 250, top: 250, angle: 30 }).scale(0.25));

    img.on('moving', function() { positionBtn(img) });
    positionBtn(img);
  });
})();
```

Comment: it's not mine, so I can't remove it, sorry

Answer (score 1):

You can overwrite the __onMouseDown function for example like this.

the target object contains __corner element `target.__corner`

Check if this is 'tr' (top right) and delete activeObject

```
    if (target.__corner === 'tr') {
        if(canvas.getActiveObject()){
            canvas.remove(canvas.getActiveObject());
        }
    }
```

Full code:

```
fabric.Canvas.prototype.__onMouseDown = function (e) {

    // accept only left clicks
    var isLeftClick  = 'which' in e ? e.which === 1 : e.button === 1;
    if (!isLeftClick && !fabric.isTouchSupported) {
        return;
    }

    if (this.isDrawingMode) {
        this._onMouseDownInDrawingMode(e);
        return;
    }

    // ignore if some object is being transformed at this moment
    if (this._currentTransform) {
        return;
    }

    var target = this.findTarget(e), 
    pointer = this.getPointer(e, true);

    if (target && target.__corner === 'tr') {
        if(this.getActiveObject()){
            this.remove(this.getActiveObject());
        }
    } else {
        // save pointer for check in __onMouseUp event
        this._previousPointer = pointer;

        var shouldRender = this._shouldRender(target, pointer),
          shouldGroup = this._shouldGroup(e, target);

        if (this._shouldClearSelection(e, target)) {
            this._clearSelection(e, target, pointer);
        } else if (shouldGroup) {
            this._handleGrouping(e, target);
            target = this.getActiveGroup();
        }

        if (target && target.selectable && !shouldGroup) {
        this._beforeTransform(e, target);
        this._setupCurrentTransform(e, target);
        }
        // we must renderAll so that active image is placed on the top canvas
        shouldRender && this.renderAll();

        this.fire('mouse:down', { target: target, e: e });
        target && target.fire('mousedown', { e: e });
    }
};
```