# remove image from canvas - fabricjs (javascript)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, fabricjs

I'm working on web application most of the part has been covered by angular js. I am stuck at a point. I used fabric.js to manipulate images on canvas and it is the best way of doing this. Everything is working fine but I can not add a close button on uploaded image like shown in image.

[image]

This angular image comes upon a canvas tag. Fabric.js gives me ability to rotate and add images but how could I close this particular image. So far I've done 
with the code is :

```
var canvas = window._canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');

    var imgElement = document.getElementById('my-image');
    var imgInstance = new fabric.Image(imgElement);
    canvas.add(imgInstance);
```

My canvas element:

```
<canvas height="282" width="181" id="c" class="lower-canvas"></canvas>
```

My uploaded image element.

```
<img style="display: none;" src="http://*******/angular.png" class="topimg canvas-img" id="my-image">
```

Below is what I am getting from fabric.js

[image]

My question is, how could I close or remove this uploaded image on canvas ? Is there any another way to doing this instead of fabric.js ? If it is, please share.. I do not want to clear canvas element from common button. I need to remove image one by one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

```
$('#remove').click(function(){
    var object = canvas.getActiveObject();
    if (!object){
        alert('Please select the element to remove');
        return '';
    }
    canvas.remove(object);
});
```

[Fiddle for remove object on button click](http://jsfiddle.net/6ydPq/73/)

[Fiddle with custom remove button on object](http://jsfiddle.net/wxao1on8/)

Comment: It is working khawer but I need to add a cross button on image itself within canvas. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Please check the second fiddle. I have used custom image, obviously you will use your own image and need to adjust the position of it a little bit

Comment: Perfect. Your second fiddle has worked as I desired. I need to modify according to me but thanks a lot to give me a way to start..

Answer (score 0):

You can delete the selected object from the canvas when the user pressed DELETE with this code:

```
window.onkeydown = onKeyDownHandler;

function onKeyDownHandler(e) {
   switch (e.keyCode) {
      case 46: // delete
         var activeObject = canvas.getActiveObject();
         if (!activeObject) canvas.remove(activeObject);
   }
   e.preventDefault(); 
};
```

You can manipulate the controls from FabricJS, but it takes some effort.
Checkout this question: [Adding Custom Delete (Back,toFront) Button to Controls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21661582/adding-custom-delete-back-tofront-button-to-controls)
and this Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/86bTc/8/