# Add custom control to Fabricjs object

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas, fabricjs

I want to to add custom control(div) to Fabric js object something like this:

[image]

I found this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21661582/adding-custom-delete-back-tofront-button-to-controls) but it has bug on rotation please see [jsfiddle](http://goo.gl/lOlrpQ)

I'm trying to find solution already few days, any suggestions are welcomed.

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/86bTc/94/

```
var btnLeft = ((e.target.width / 2)  -10 )* cos(angle) + ((e.target.height / 2) +25) * sin(angle);
var btnTop = -((e.target.height / 2) +25 )* cos(angle) + ((e.target.width / 2) -10 ) * sin(angle);
```

You have to add the rotation effect to LEFT and TOP of your absolute positioned element.

I changed the positioned element with a small div, so you do not get tricked by the baseline of text that makes the 'p' element look in wrong position.

Comment: Thank you so much but it still have a bug check this out when you rotating div rotates too http://jsfiddle.net/86bTc/95/

Answer (score 1):

Might be that solution is good for you? [Fabric js custom controls](http://pixolith.github.io/fabricjs-customise-controls-extension/example/index.html)

Comment: I need this feature in my angular 7 project. I installed this module using 
*npm install fabric-customise-controls --save* , 
imported it using
import 'fabric-customise-controls';
but when I try to use 
fabric.Canvas.prototype.customiseControls({ }, function() {
    canvas.renderAll();
} );
It gives me error of property customiseControls does not exist on Canvas object.